# Find specific anchor href and add onclick function

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor tag, I want when the user clicks it, it runs a function instead of  redirecting to another page. 
I cannot modify the tag directly instead I'm using JQuery, the only thing I can define is the `href` value, so here in my code I have set the `href` value to `tasks` and then in jquery I'm trying to find that specific anchor with `href=tasks` and add a `onclick` function to run the function `clickme`

```
$("a[href$='task']").onclick(clickme);

function clickme(){
alert("Hi");
return false;
}
```

However, I get this error message in [jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/2qLcgfLm/2/)

`{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

Comment: `$("a[href$='task']").click(clickme);`

Comment: [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yLazL30y/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method as `onclick` in jQuery. You need  to use [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/),

```
$("a[href$='task']").click(clickme);
```

OR,

```
$("a[href$='task']").on( "click", clickme);
```

Note: `click` is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yLazL30y/1/)

Comment: @Tushar, You didn't need to delete your answer and Thanks for Fiddle

Comment: Hi, thanks guys. I have tried in my own fiddle page but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Oh sorry! my bad.. I have imported the wrong jquery without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the error is because since you are using `onclick` event ( which is invalid event ) , the method binding cannot be intercepted. By changing the bindings to either attaching a click event handler .on or binding a .click event, you can either use `return false;` or use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the page from navigating.

```
$("a[href$='task']").click(clickme);
function clickme(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert("Hi");
}
```

OR

```
 $("a[href$='task']").click(clickme);
function clickme(e){
alert("Hi");
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
$("a").live({click:function(){  ... });
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)